# Inserting and removing element in a double link list

Tags: c, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct dlist
{
    int data;
        struct dlist *next, *prev;
}dlist;

dlist* insert_begin(dlist *h,int d)
{
    dlist *temp = (dlist*)malloc(sizeof(dlist));
    temp->data = d;
    temp->next = temp->prev= NULL;
    if(h==NULL)
    {
        h=temp;
      //  t=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next = h;
        h->prev = temp;
        h = temp;
    }
    return h;
}
dlist* delete_begin(dlist *h)
{
    dlist *r = h;
    if(r==NULL)
    {
        printf("empty list");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        dlist *ptr = r;
        //ptr = r;
        r=r->next;
        r->prev = NULL;
        free(ptr);
    }
    return r;
}
dlist* delete_end(dlist *h)
{
    dlist *r = h;
    if(r==NULL)
    {
        printf("empty list");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        while(r->next)
            r=r->next;

        dlist *p = r;
        (r->prev)->next= NULL;
        free(p);
        return r;
    }

    //return r;
}
void display(dlist *h)
{
    dlist *r = h;
  //  printf("%d",r->data);

    //printf("ajay");
    while(r)
    {
        printf("%d ---- >",r->data);

        r=r->next;
    }
}
void main()
{
    dlist *d=NULL;

    d = insert_begin(d,2);
   d=  insert_begin(d,3);
   d= insert_begin(d,4);
  d=  insert_begin(d,5);
    display(d);
    d = delete_begin(d);
    printf("After deletion1");
    display(d);
    d= delete_end(d);
    printf("After deletion2");
     display(d);                              // infinite elements are displaying on screen

}
```

Above is the code i was tring to write for inserting and deleting element in a double link list. My inserting part and deleting a node from beginning, both are working absolutely fine. I am facing problem in the delete_end() function.
When i am compiled and run the code then, it is continuously printing on the screen. Need help.

Comment: Your delete_end() function doesn't really make sense. You have `h`, `r`, and `p` that all point to the same thing. You create `p`, do nothing to it, and then `free()` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `delete_end()`, the code doesn't handle the case of a 1 node list, in which `r != NULL`, but `r->prev == NULL` and `r->next == NULL`. This presents a problem when the code attempts `(r->prev)->next = NULL`.

`delete_begin()` doesn't handle a 1 node list either. `r=r->next` could set `r == NULL`, followed by `r->prev == NULL`.

Back to `delete_end()`, the code should return `h`, not `r`.

Comment: ok. That is one case , you bring notice to me... but i have inserted 4 nodes, then i am trying to delete one. So 1 node list case has not arise yet.

Comment: @AjayKhetan - I updated my answer, delete_end() needs to return h if the list is not empty, but it's returning r instead.

Comment: thanx a lot.. that 1 node list case is a problem. Along with this, i have to return the address of first node and i am returning the address of last node. got it.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two serious problems with the function.

First of all it returns the pointer `r` that can be unequal to the address of the head node due to the loop

```
while(r->next)
    r=r->next;
```

However you need to return the pointer that points to the head node of the list.

Also if the pointer `r` points to the head node then `r->prev` is equal to `NULL`. Thus this statement

```
(r->prev)->next= NULL;
```

can result in undefined behavior of the program.

I can suggest the following function implementation

```
dlist* delete_end( dlist *h )
{
    if( h == NULL )
    {
        printf("empty list");
    }
    else
    {
        dlist **r = &h;

        while ( ( *r )->next ) r = &( *r )->next;

        dlist *p = *r;

        if ( ( *r )->prev )
        {        
            ( *r )->prev->next = NULL;
        }

        *r = ( *r )->prev;

        free( p );
    }

    return h;
}
```